# SQL use FOR... IN for cursor

Tags: sql, select, cursor, for-in-loop

Is it possible to use FOR...IN to read a cursor information line by line?

for example:

```
var V_CURSOR REFCURSOR;
declare
%Some declaration

Begin 
%Some codes  where we fill up the cursor in PL/SQL section
        FOR line IN :V_CURSOR LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(line);
        END LOOP;

End;
/
```

Thx

Comment: Have you done any research? You should do this, and if you still don't have the answer, then include your findings in the question.

Comment: Yes and unfortunately I am new in SQL so it is difficult even to what should I look for :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=plsql+cursor+loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and the code you have up there is pretty much spot on,
The syntax for the FOR..IN loop in cursors looks like this:

```
FOR [record_index] in [cursor_name]
    LOOP
       [statements]
    END LOOP;
```

Hope this helps.